# Views not found after migrating to .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I migrated an ASP.NET CORE MVC project from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6.

After making relevant changes, the project compiles and starts seemingly OK, but the views aren't found.

Root path is set `app.Environment.ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` and the path to views seems to be correct. This is the error message that follows:

[image]

The Login.cshtml is in /Views/Account folder, and Build Action is set to Content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue after migrating to .Net 6, and this is the solution that works for me.  I checked the list of packages that I have and saw that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design outdated version was still part of the project, then I removed it and the solution started working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: This was the same package I had to remove to make things work.

Comment: This saved the day for me! Not sure why I didn't notice this answer during the 3 hours I spent troubleshooting this issue, but really happy to have found it now.

Comment: This is the actual issue. Thanks for saving my time!

Answer (score 4):

For my case, it worked after removing the package of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2.0. Not sure why this version was still siting in the project after migrating from Net 5 to 6.

Comment: Remove Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2.0 It's worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

your account folder maybe missing in areas like [image]

if it is ok then
in **Startup.cs**

in this method  **public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)**

paste this code

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Comment: I'm not using areas, I don't think it's mandatory. At least it hasn't been in previous versions. Also I am using endpoints and they're correctly configured. ASP.NET Core 6 introduced the new minimal hosting model, so they're now configured in Program.cs instead of Startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

An outdated Razor package messed up the pipeline somehow. I'm not sure why.
Removing the Razor package solved the issue.

Comment: Can you give any more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

@OIbuoye answer worked for me. I also had to add the following to my Startup.cs. This was for a Web API that also has some Views for confirmation pages, errors pages etc...

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I had recently installed the latest SDK (7.0.401) but it was not compatible with the version of visual studio I was running.  Any website i published would display the view not found error.  Uninstalling the SDK resolved the issue.