# Can't find views after upgrading to .net 6 and deployed on server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I am having a weird issue after I upgraded a very simple .net core 3.1 MVC app to .net 6. I used the upgrade assistant and also followed the Microsoft's guideline very carefully. The absurdity of the problem is that on my local machine everything works fine, but on the server I keep getting the following error. Also, prior to the upgrade, it worked fine both locally and on the server:

[image]

I did mention it totally works on my computer, but also just as a proof that the file it says it cannot find does exist:

[image]

Here is the code for the `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup

    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>

            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();//.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddKendo();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc().UseEndpoints(x => x.MapControllers());
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>

            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            });
        }
    }
```

and just in case the code for Program.cs

```
public class Program

    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

                    if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment?.EnvironmentName?.Equals("Debug") == true)

                    {
                        logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.AddDebug();
                    }

                    logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
                    {
                        SourceName = "wcb.ACIi.web"
                    });
                })
                .Build();
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/razor-compiler/issues/225) might be related. Maybe check your version of the .NET 6 SDK. [Based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71292380/120955) you may also need to check that you don't have outdated Razor-related packages in your project.

Comment: The server is already confirmed to have the .net 6 installed. But thanks

Answer (score -1):

If including views in the main assembly is not essential you can:
add this to your property group: <UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>

This will prevent including the views in the main dll and create the other.  This helped us as we found that on the build server dotnet publish was not creating the the AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument namespace (we used dotPeek to determine this).  All of the microsoft targets were installed and it still would not build correctly.